# Virtuemart stuck in offline mode

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I uncheck the "offline mode" box in the Virtuemart backend but the site still displays the offline message.  I have tried adding define('PSHOP_IS_OFFLINE', ''); 
 to the config file but no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: have you turn on offline mode in joomla configuration file? if yes turn off offline mode in joomla configuration

Comment: I was actually seeing somebody's offline message displayed from an article haha